# onChange is one character on delay - Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am new to React and Hooks.

I create a simple search bar where the user can type some text.

However, if I `console.log` the state after the `onChange`, it is always one character behind.

For example:
If I type "pizza", the `console.log` shows "pizz"

**My component**

```
export default function SearchBar({handlerSearchBar}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [searchBarQuery, setSearchBarQuery] = React.useState([""])

function handleChange(event){
    setSearchBarQuery(event.target.value)
    // handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)
    console.log(searchBarQuery)
}



return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
            id="standard-full-width"
            label="Searchbar"
            style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginRight: 40 }}
            placeholder="Write your query"
            // helperText="The results will appear below!"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
            }}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    </form>
);
}
```

After some research ([onChange event updates state with 1 character delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557512/onchange-event-updates-state-with-1-character-delay)), I understand that `setState`  is asynchronous.

So I tried varies solutions to make it work:

**1) Solution One**

```
function handleChange(event) {
    let text = event.target.value;
    setSearchBarQuery({
        text: text
    });
    console.log(searchBarQuery)
}
```

But I have the same problem (last character is not captured)

**2) Solution Two**

```
function handleChange(event) {
    let text = event.target.value;
    setSearchBarQuery({
        text: text
    }, ()=>console.log(searchBarQuery));
}
```

But I get `Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().`

**3) Solution Three**

```
   async function handleChange(event) {
        await setSearchBarQuery({text: event.target.value});
        console.log(searchBarQuery)
    }
```

But I have the same problem (last character is not captured)

Comment: Your state updates correctly, just not where you want to see, move your `console.log` to `useEffect` hook, and you get the correct result. Your second solution is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, useState is async function. When you use useState inside functional Component, you have to handle variable in useEffect to see change of variable like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Search message inside useEffect: ", search);
  }, [search]);

  return <input onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it works also without `e.persist();`

Comment: Is this method good from production/performance point of view?