# useEffect makes onChange and typing lag/slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a website where the user can type what he is looking for in a search bar.

Initially, I had a problem with the fact that `onChange` was one character behind the user search. For example, if the user search for "banana", the search was "banan".
I understood that the problem comes form the fact that `setState` is asynchronous.
[onChange is one character on delay - Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887235/onchange-is-one-character-on-delay-hooks)

To avoid this problem, I introduced the `useEffect` component in my code. It works.
**However** now, if the user types some words, the words he types are not displayed immediately inside the search bar. They are displayed after few moments, as if it were a delay between what the user types and what it is displayed.

**My searchbar component**

```
export default function SearchBar({handlerSearchBar}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [searchBarQuery, setSearchBarQuery] = React.useState([""])


    function handleChange(event) {
        setSearchBarQuery(event.target.value);
        console.log(searchBarQuery)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Search message inside useEffect: ", searchBarQuery);
        handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)
    });

    return (
        <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField
                required
                id="standard-full-width"
                label="Searchbar"
                style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginRight: 40 }}
                placeholder="Write your query"
                // helperText="The results will appear below!"
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,

                }}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```

**handlerSearchBar function**

It a function that is passing the results from my search-bar component to its parents and then, to its grandparents (`SearchForm`).

The grandparents `SearchForm` is setting one of its state to what is passed via the searchbar `handlerSearchBar` function:

```
function SearchForm() {
    const [searchBarQueryParent, setSearchBarQueryParent] = React.useState([""])

    function handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery) {
        setSearchBarQueryParent(searchBarQuery)
        console.log(searchBarQuery)
    }
    return (something)
}
```

My question is: why is the display of the search words so much delayed than the their actual typing?

I think what is happening is that `useEffect` is called for each key stroke, and that is what it is so slow.
I tried to call `useEffect` on `onSubmit` but there is no improvement.

Or it is my `handlerSearchBar` function that makes everything slow

Comment: Just finished replication of your code in sandbox, and... it works fine, no visible lag at all.

Comment: I start to think the issue is the function `handlerSearchBar `. If I comment it, there is no lag but without it I do not see how I can pass `searchBarQuery ` to the grandparent

Comment: In your case you can lift up state from `SearchBar` to `SearchFrom` component, in other words make `SearchBar` "fully controlled".

Comment: But again, I see no issue with your current implementation. It works good. Maybe the source of this problem is in other parts of application.

Comment: If I comment out `handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)` there is no lag. But clearly, the props are not set to the grandparent `SearchFrom ` if I commented `handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)` out.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make minimal reproduced example, so we can observe lag with our own eyes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by changing from `onChange` to `onBlur`.

I am not totally sure why the change works, but it does work.

Comment: the 2nd param of useEffect should be [], otherwise, it would be expensive render.

Comment: `onChange` update the state on every key entered, but `onBlur` helps you, because this will update the state when you exit the TextField

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try to make it so that the `useEffect` fires only when `searchBarQuery` has been updated. i.e. as a callback upon `setSearchBarQuery`. You might do;

```js
//...
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Search message inside useEffect: ", searchBarQuery);
        handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)
    }, [searchBarQuery]);
// ...
```

Note the second argument, an array, in useEffect to make that only run when that item has changed.

Comment: Thanks, however the `searchBarQuery ` will change for every stroke, therefore `useEffect` is called for each stroke and thus is `    handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)` which i think is the cause of the lag

Comment: That would be true if this `console.log("Search message inside useEffect: ", searchBarQuery);` does not lag.

Comment: If I comment `handlerSearchBar(searchBarQuery)`, the `console.log("Search message inside useEffect: ", searchBarQuery)` does not lag

Comment: Do you see this `console.log(searchBarQuery)` in the  SearchForm as quick as expected?

Comment: No, it does lag

Comment: Well, the set up might be letting you down. First, I don't really understand why you'd want to maintain the state of the same item in two places, i.e. in the SearchBar and again in the SearchForm. My recommendation would be that you do away with one,, most likely the one in the `SearchBar` and  leave the one in the `SearchForm`, and call your `handlerSearchBar` in `handleChange` like `handlerSearchBar(event.target.value)`;

Comment: Because together with the `SearchBar` there are other components such as `location`, `datePicker` etc. If I call `handlerSearchBar` in `handleChange` `useEffect`, the search is incomplete. Ex. if the user types `pizza`, the `handleChange` will catch only "pizz"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202520/discussion-between-john-mutuma-and-fbso).

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to the game here, but what I did was to use a `debounce` function. This will check the input values every 1 sec, and will remove the lag as well

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui';

function SomeComp(props) {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(null);
  const [fetchDataSwitch, setFetchDataSwitch] = useState(false);

  // Limit the number of requests sent
  const debouncedFetchData = debounce((cb) => {
    cb(!fetchDataSwitch);
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    debouncedFetchData((res) => {
      setFetchDataSwitch(res);
    });
  }, [myValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // check if input Is valid
    // fire API request

    return () => {
      // Clean up
    };
  }, [fetchDataSwitch]);

  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        inputProps: { min: 0 }
      }}
      fullWidth
      placeholder={'Max transit time...'}
      type={'number'}
      value={myValue || ''}
      onChange={({ target }) => setMyValue(target.value)}
    />
  );
}

SomeComp.propTypes = {};

SomeComp.defaultProps = {};

export default SomeComp;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```